# Are Mongoose virtuals messed up?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

Ok, so I have this SchemaOptions, Schema, Constructor and virtual.

```
var schemaOptions = {
  toObject: { virtuals: true }, toJSON: { virtuals: true }
};

var clientSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
  company: { type: String, trim: true, required: true, unique: true  },
  monthly_cost: { type: Number, trim: true, required: true },
  sms_cost: { type: Number, trim: true, required: true },
  ...
}, schemaOptions);

var Client = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);

clientSchema.virtual('creationDate').get(function () {
  return dateFormat(this._id.getTimestamp(), 'isoDate');
});
```

Further down I have this route:
(Note the commented code in the for-loop, we will remove this comment later)

```
app.get('/superadmin', function(req, res) {
  Client.find({}, 'company monthly_cost sms_cost', function (err, docs) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    for (var i = 0, tot=docs.length; i < tot; i++) {
      // docs[i].creationDate = 'strange variable ' + i; 
    }

    console.log(docs); 

    res.render('superadmin/index', { 
      title: 'Superadmin',
      docs: docs,
      path: req.route.path,
    });
  });
});
```

and in my Jade view I have the following pieces of code:

```
p #{docs};
each client in docs
  tr
    td #{client.company}
    td #{client.creationDate}
...
```

But here come the problems:

In my route I have: `console.log(docs);` which output a string similar to 'YYYY-MM-DD', which is expected and good.

Early in my view I have: `console.log(docs);` which also output the right string: 'YYYY-MM-DD', which is expected and good.

BUT the: #{client.creationDate} in my view doenst output anything!! I dont understand why.

If we now activate the commented line in my for loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0, tot=docs.length; i < tot; i++) {
  docs[i].creationDate = 'strange variable ' + i; 
}
```

... `#{client.creationDate}` WILL output `'strange variable [0-2]'`. But my two earlier `console.log(docs)` will still output the expected creationDate string.

I dont understand this.. it seems that creationDate is two variables at the same time.

Mongoose Virtuals is driving me crazy, and I really dont understand WHY I'm complaining with them when it anyway seems that can add keyvalues on the fly to a fetched mongoose object. Ok, they dont show up in a console.log... but they are there somehow and I can use them like this: `#{client.creationDate}` in my view.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(docs)` when `creationDate` is there as expected?

Comment: When i output the whole document trough console.log, the output for .creationDate is correct. That is "YYYY-MM-DD" generated by the virtual function. But when I try to output just one single .creationDate like this in the route: console.log(doc[0].creationDate) tis like the value doesnt exist anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is out of order:

```
var Client = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);

clientSchema.virtual('creationDate').get(function () {
  return dateFormat(this._id.getTimestamp(), 'isoDate');
});
```

You must completely configure your schema BEFORE you "compile" it to a model. It's not dynamic. Once the model is compiled, further changes to the schema don't take affect.

Comment: You are my god. I't would probably take a long time before i figured this out by myself.